# Creating a Windows Azure Service through the REST API on Python

Tags: python, rest, azure

I'm trying to create a service on Windows Azure using the REST API and Python. The code is as follows:

```
def create_service(self):
            subscription_id = self.get_user_subscription_id()
            auth = self.get_user_cert_data()

            if auth is None or subscription_id is None:
                    return [(False, "Datos de autenticacion incorrectos")]
            else:
                    key_file, cert_file = auth

            service_name = str(int(time.time()*100))

            try:

                    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(self.AZURE_SERVER, self.AZURE_PORT, key_file=key_file, cert_file=cert_file)
                    uri = "https://%s/%s/services/hostedservices" % (self.AZURE_SERVER,subscription_id)
                    service_create_xml = '''
    <CreateHostedService xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure">
      <ServiceName>%s</ServiceName>
      <Label>%s</Label>
      <Description>Service %s created by the IM</Description>
      <Location>West Europe</Location>
    </CreateHostedService> 
                    ''' % (service_name, base64.b64encode(service_name), service_name )
                    conn.request('POST', uri, body = service_create_xml, headers = {'x-ms-version' : '2013-03-01', 'ContentType' : 'application/xml'})
                    resp = conn.getresponse()
            except Exception, ex:
                    self.logger.exception("Error creando el service")
                    return None

            if resp.status != 201:
                    self.logger.error("Error creando el service: Codigo " + str(resp.status) + " Reason: " + str(resp.reason))
                    return None

            return service_name
```

However, for some unknown reason the response is always Error 400 Bad Request. Anyone knows what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For headers here:

> headers = {'x-ms-version' : '2013-03-01', '**ContentType**' :
>   'application/xml'}

Try using **`Content-Type`** instead of **`ContentType`**

Comment: Oh man, you 'saved' my life again. I was unable to detect the bug. Now working perfectly. Many thanks again.

Comment: Done! (in both questions). Sorry, I'm new on Stackoverflow